# How to create RAW image?

Tags: image, matlab

I'm building one part of H264 encoder. For testing system, I need to created input image for encoding. We have a programme for read image to RAM file format to use.

My question is how to create a RAW file: bitmap or tiff (I don't want to use compressed format link JPEG)? I googled and recognize alot of raw file type. **So what type i should use and how to create?** . I think i will use C/C++ or Matlab to create raw file.

P/S: my need format is : YUV ( or Y Cb Cr) 4:2:0 and 8 bit colour deepth

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28414/ap_imgraw.htm

Comment: So, you are after YUYV (aka YUV2) or UYVY (which is the same with different byteorder within each 32-bit dword) To make things a bit more complicated, one has to know that jpeg and mpeg use different RGB->YUV matrices and different ranges of colors in each channel. They do not necessarily go from 0..255, but from 16-240...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest raw format is just a stream of numbers, representing the pixels. Each raw format can be associated with metadata such as:

- width, heigth
- width / image row (ie. gstreamer & x-window align each row to dword boundaries)
- bits per pixel
- byte format / endianness  (if 16 bits per pixel or more)
- number of image channels
- color system HSV, RGB, Bayer, YUV
- order of channels, e.g. RGBA, ABGR, GBR
- planar vs. packed (or FOURCC code)

or this metadata can be just an internal specification...

I believe one of the easiest approaches (after of course a steep learning curve :) is to use e.g. gstreamer, where you can use existing file/stream *sources* that read data from camera, file, pre-existing jpeg etc. and pass those raw streams inside a defined *pipeline*. One useful element is a *filesink*, which would simply write a single or few successive raw data frames to your filesystem. The gstreamer infrastructure has possibly hundreds of converters and filters, btw. including h264 encoder...

I would bet that if you just dump your memory, that output will conform already to some [FOURCC](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php) -format (also recognized by gstreamer).